# Linux command to check the count returned from grep command is greater than specific no

Tags: linux, unix, command

Iam new to linux.

Iam trying to count the  occurance of a string in a file and have to check the count is greater than particular no.

I have following command to get the count of the string from a file

```
grep -c "CPU" /opt/core.log
```

It will returns  the count of that string from that file

Along with this command can I compare that result with any number .
I tried many ways but getting the o/p

like  grep -c "CPU" /opt/core.log | awk '{print $1>=30}'

Comment: Something like `grep -c "CPU" /opt/core.log | awk '$1>=30 {print}'` ?

Answer (score 0):

first count using grep -o because grep -c will count only one occurence per line. then use if else logic to know if it is greater than or not your number.

```
    cat test.txt
    CPU is main part of computer. CPU should be 32 bit or 64 bit.
    laptop with less CPU is not good.
    

    a=$(grep -ow "CPU" test.txt|wc -l|sed 's/^$//g')
    echo $a
    3

    if [[ $a -gt 2 ]]; then; echo "Greater"; else; echo "Equal or Smaller"; fi
    Greater

    if [[ $a -gt 3 ]]; then; echo "Greater"; else; echo "Equal or Smaller"; fi
    Equal or Smaller
```